# Open WMTS query parameter encoding with "+" character in QGis

Tags: qgis, wmts, encoding

I am trying to create a WMTS endpoint with query parameters in the urls that contain a `+` character. So my resource url looks like this:

```
<ResourceURL format="image/png" template="http://localhost/wmts/{TileMatrix}/{TileCol}/{TileRow}.png?formula=(B8-B4)/(B8+B4)" resourceType="tile"/>
```

The formula query parameter contains a `+` character, which is not escaped when opening the endpoint in QGis. So in the html requests made by QGis, the formula is passed unaltered, and so the server interprets the `+` as white space. The specific calls look like this:

http://localhost/wmts/2/1/0.png?formula=(B8-B4)/(B8+B4)

But should look like this (plus sign escaped)

http://localhost/wmts/2/1/0.png?formula=(B8-B4)/(B8%2BB4)

To work around this, I tried to manually escape the character by changing the endpoint to

```
<ResourceURL format="image/png" template="http://localhost/wmts/{TileMatrix}/{TileCol}/{TileRow}.png?formula=(B8-B4)/(B8%2BB4)" resourceType="tile"/>
```

But in that case, QGis encodes the `%` symbol, leading to a dobule escaped formula that looks like this:

```
http://localhost/wmts/2/1/0.png?formula=B8%252BB4
```

So it looks like QGis escapes `%` but it does not escape `+` characters.

Is there any way to control this behavior?

Comment: I understand that + is a reserved character. But I think QGIS might be inconsistent. If the url is assumed to be encoded, then + represents a whitespace and % should be left as-is. If not, + should be assumed to be "unencoded" and both should be escaped. According to wikipedia, % is not a reserved character and should not be escaped in urls (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Comment: You're right QGIS appears inconsistent - misunderstood the query, my bad.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be a bug report rather than a question on StackExchange.